# Rails 4 .times RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm converting my app over to Rails 4 and have hit a stumbling block. In prior Rails versions I could have a line that did this:

```
<div class="inventory">
    <dl>
        <dt>Lots in Inventory</dt>
           <dd>
               <% @employee.lots.count(:group => :product_id).each do |product_id, number| %>
                 <%= Product.find(product_id).product_name %> = <%= number %>
           <% end %>
            </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

And everything worked fine. It appears that I need to replace .each with .times in Rails 4. However, when I do that I end up with an error that says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EmployeesController#show

Couldn't find Product with id=0
```

That's because there is no Product with an ID of 0, it starts with 1.

How can I get around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you  can make it 
<%= Product.where(id: product_id).try(&:product_name) %> = <%= number %>

Comment: Egalitarian, sadly that didn't work.

Comment: @Egalitarian, replace where with `find!` and the code in your comment would work. But this will be lot of queries towards the database and therefore not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any fancy methods but you can do something like this:

(for simplification I ignore .erb)

```
hash = Hash.new
@employee.lots.each do |lot|
    hash[lot.product_id]||=0
    hash[lot.product_id]+=1
end
hash.each_pair do |product_id, number|
    # <%= Product.find(product_id).product_name %> = <%= number %>
end
```

Other bad thing I notice is that you will use Product.find awful many times, each one resulting in a query to DB.
I will suggest eager loading (you can read about it in [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)).
If you use eager loading you can safely do the following

```
hash = Hash.new
@employee.lots.each do |lot|
    hash[lot.product]||=0
    hash[lot.product]+=1
end
hash.each_pair do |product, number|
    # <%= "#{product.name} = #{number}" %>
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This because `times` only yields an index, you have no more your product id and number.

Rollback your code or explain what you desired.

Comment: I'm trying to have the application list the quantities of each product (or lot of the product) the employee has in inventory.